# serialize queryset via django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to use updating version of DRF. I used code from tutorial

```
serializer = SnippetSerializer(Snippet.objects.all(), many=True)
serializer.data
```

I should get

```
[{
  'pk': 1, 'title': u'', 'code': u'foo = "bar"\n', 'linenos': False, 
  'language': u'python', 'style': u'friendly'
 }, {
  'pk': 2, 'title': u'', 'code': u'print "hello, world"\n', 'linenos': False, 
  'language': u'python', 'style': u'friendly'
}]
```

but I got:

```
[OrderedDict([
  ('pk', 1), ('title', u''), ('code', u'foo = "bar"\n'), 
  ('linenos', False), ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')
 ]), 
 OrderedDict([
  ('pk', 2), ('title', u''), ('code', u'print "hello, world"\n'), ('linenos', False), 
  ('language', 'python'), ('style', 'friendly')
 ])
]
```

Please explain how get correctly results?

Comment: Result is correct. OrderedDict is like a normal dictionary (that you expect), except it will retain its order, which a normal dictionary does not do. Other than this, it works exactly like a normal dictionary. In case you wonder, `OrderedDict` is from python's `collections` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

Comment: What results aren't correct? You can convert an `OrderedDict` to a `dict` by calling `dict(serializer.data)`, but then you lose any field ordering.

Comment: then is tutorial in documentation old?

Comment: when I did dict(serializer.data) got 

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required`

Comment: @AlexYar they are wrong

Answer (score 3):

if you need valid json, you can do

```
import json
serializer = SnippetSerializer(Snippet.objects.all(), many=True)
json.dumps(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Actually this is better:

from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

json = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

Answer (score 1):

**Results are correct. DRF explicitly uses OrderedDict in the serialization process.**

**OrderedDict:**

OrderedDict is a subclass of dict. You can perform all the operations of a normal python dictionary on an `OrderedDict`.

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict),

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they
>   remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an
>   ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys
>   were first added.

Also, if you need a regular python dictionary, you can use `dict()` on `serializer.data` as [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359284/kevin-brown) also suggested.

```
dict(serializer.data)  # Converts to regular python dict
```

Comment: Wrong. You can't call dict on serializer.data because it is of type rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList